# App still saves data to iCloud even if it's turned off

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, icloud

I've made it possible to show inserted data on other devices through iCloud, but even when I turn iCloud off for my app (Documents&Data -> My App Off), after a few seconds the entered data appears on the other device (which has iCloud enabled) also.

Does this mean that even if

```
- (void)initializeiCloudAccessWithCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL available)) completion {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSURL * _iCloudJuurkataloog = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
    if (_iCloudJuurkataloog != nil) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"iCloud available at: %@", _iCloudJuurkataloog);
            completion(TRUE);
        });
    }
    else {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"iCloud not available or the app is running in simulator");
            completion(FALSE);
        });
    }
});
}
```

returns "iCloud not available", it is only informative message and I have to control saving to iCloud manually, because if I won't the data will be saved anyway?

**Edit:**
It seems that when turning iCloud off from Documents&Data under Documents&Data (I guess it turns iCloud off for all apps as it says "Allow apps to store documents and data in iCloud" for enabled mode), everything works as expected - NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification is received and I won't be able to send any data to iCloud or receive any data from iCloud.

But when turning off iCloud for specific app (Documents&Data -> My App Off), NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification is not received, URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier returns nil as if iCloud isn't available, the app can still send updates to iCloud, BUT it won't be able to receive them.

Am I getting something wrong or is there a reason to believe that this is the Apple bug?

By the way, when toggling the iCloud switch for specific app while running from Xcode on a device, I get a SIGKILL - maybe a Xcode bug?

Comment: I'm not sure, but if you disable iCloud for an app Apple can't just shut it out completely, it needs to give the app a chance to move it's data out of iCloud. This requires allowing the app at least some partial access.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. Why does it turn off iCloud completely from  Documents&Data -> Documents&Data then and after all, it's still possible to SEND data while Documents&Data -> My App Off, but not to receive it.